# How to send table column values from a Javascript page to a C# page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have values that come from a dynamically created table from it's selected rows. inside each selected row i want all the td.innerText values that belong to be sent to a C# page, but i don't know how to. I was using JSON but I dont know if i used it properly.

```
function selectedRows() 
{

var selectedItems = $('#ScannedLabelTable').find(':checkbox:checked').parents('tr');

 var serial, kanbanNumber, customer, description, quantity;

    $.each(selectedItems, function (i, item) {


        var td = $(this).children('td');

        for (var i = 0; i < td.length; ++i)
        {

            serial = td[1].innerText;
            kanbanNumber = td[2].innerText;
            customer = td[3].innerText;
            description = td[4].innerText;
            quantity = td[5].innerText;

        }

        console.log(serial + ' ' + kanbanNumber + ' ' + customer + ' ' + description + ' ' + quantity);



    });

   $.ajax({
                    url: SEND_TO_TEXTFILE_PAGE
                    , data: "labelSerial=" + serial + "&kanbanNumber=" + kanbanNumber + "&customer="
                            + customer + "&description=" + description + "&quantity=" + quantity 
                    , dataType: 'json'
                    , success: function (status) {
                                                    if (status.Error) {
                                                        alert(status.Error);
                                                    }
                                                }
                    , error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
                });


 }
```

Comment: I suggest you should make use of `form` to send your data from client side (javascript) to server side (C#). That can ease up certain things for you.

Comment: @kumar please show me a slight example

Comment: Can you show your html here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ ? This would make things more clear for me as to what to show you

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry I must have read this too quickly. This should do it. create an array and add the data object to it in the loop.

If you just create a json object using key value pairs you can send that object to your c# controller.

```
   function selectedRows() {
        var selectedItems = $('#ScannedLabelTable').find(':checkbox:checked').parents('tr');
        var serial, kanbanNumber, customer, description, quantity;
        var dataArray = new Array();

        $.each(selectedItems, function (i, item) {

            var td = $(this).children('td');

            for (var i = 0; i < td.length; ++i)
            {
                var InfoObject = {
                    serial: td[1].innerText;
                    kanbanNumber: td[2].innerText;
                    customer: td[3].innerText;
                    description: td[4].innerText;
                    quantity: td[5].innerText;
                };
                dataArray.push(InfoObject);
            }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: SEND_TO_TEXTFILE_PAGE
        , data: dataArray
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function (status) {
            if (status.Error) {
                alert(status.Error);
            }
         }
         , error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
    });
}
```

Comment: declaring variables inside a for loop is not going to make it in to a array